# How can I get the value of the name only on this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the output array when I do

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
result.values.each {|element|
puts element
}
```

Result:

```
{"id"=>3, "code"=>"3", "name"=>"Market", "status"=>"A", "refcode"=>"001"}
{"id"=>4, "code"=>"4", "name"=>"Mall", "status"=>"A", "refcode"=>"002"}
```

From this array, I only want to get the name value. I tried this 
puts result['data'][0]['name'] and it worked fine but I want to get all the name in the array

This is my expected output

```
Market
Mall
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and over each element, to access it's 'name' key, like:

```
p array.map { |element| element['name'] }
# ["Market", "Mall"]
```

I think it'd be something like:

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body) 
result.values.map { |element| element['name'] }
# ["Market", "Mall"]
```

Since with `each` and `puts` you're only iterating and printing the hashes in the array, you could access the 'name' key from `result.values`.

Answer (score 1):

I wont modify much. Since your name element is at position 3. access it like array because you are using values.each

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
result.values.each {|element|
puts element[2]
}
```